# How to remove the footer in Oracle Apex

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

How do I remove the "Release" footer at the bottom of the Oracle APEX template?  I can't see it in the Global page, or anywhere obvious in the page templates or user interface attributes (Shared Components).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS to remove footer:

```
.t-Footer{
  display: none;
}
```

Other commands to remove parts of footer:

```
.t-Footer-top{
    Display: none !important;
}
.t-Footer-srMode{
    Display: none !important;
}
.t-Footer-version{
    Display: none !important;
}
.t-Footer-apex{
    Display:none !important;
}
```

not sure if "!important" is needed

Comment: For me this hides the footer but fails to reclaim the whitespace that the footer occupied. This leads to the vertical scroll bar displaying in in circumstances where it is unnecessary to scroll down into empty white space of the hidden footer.

Comment: UPDATE: The hidden footer's un-reclaimed whitespace and the page's unnecessary scroll bar are caused by the min-height: 100vh; property of t-Body-content (along with display: flex). To remove the whitespace and scroll bar set:  .t-Body-content {min-height: initial;}

Answer (score 4):

Footer is defined in page templates.
You would need to remove html footer from template body, make sure to remove it from any page template you are using.
Otherwise you could use css to hide it.

EDIT for clarity:

To edit the template for a page, you can do that either under Shared Components or on the page itself.

While editing the page, there's 2 places you could look (I'm assuming Apex 22 at this point):

1. on the left side, find Templates > Page. Expand Page, and right-click the name below it (maybe "Standard"). Click Edit.
2. on the right side under Appearance, find the "Page Template" value. Click the ">" icon to select the template, then click "Edit Component".

Both of those options will take you to the same place as Shared Components > Templates > [the name of your page template]

On that page, you're looking for the HTML <footer> tags, which are usually in the Body section of the template. To remove the app version, look for substitution variable #APP_VERSION# and delete it.

Note that **if your page template is part of a theme which is subscribed to Standard Theme**, it will be read-only, and you won't see a Save button at the top. You would need to either (a) copy it to a new custom theme, and then change your application to use that theme instead, or (b) unsubscribe your theme from the Standard Theme - this will make it read-write, but prevent it from receiving any Oracle updates to the Standard Theme. This is outside the scope of the current question, but please see [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/apex-5.1/HTMDB/managing-themes-and-subscriptions.htm#HTMDB30230)

Comment: Specifically, edit the Page Template for your page, scroll down to the Body section, and delete the `#APP_VERSION#` substitution string.

Comment: @kfinity, how do you edit the *Page Template for your page* to make this change? Under  Shared Components? On the page itself? Please be specific for newcomers to Apex.

Comment: @Parfait - added some details about editing page templates

Answer (score 1):

Go to your page template and remove it or add it as css

```
footer{display:none!important}
```

And voila.